# Converting Symbols (Copyright, Reg etc)

Tags: php, html

I am trying to sanitise database input and found a problem with the Ⓡ character.

Ⓡ converts to

```
&#9415;
```

Even with html_entity_decode around the variable.

This is a problem because the field is only meant to allow 4 characters in the database.

® Actually works though and is treated as a single character.

I have the same problem with Ⓒ vs ©.

As far as I know they are just html entities so should be decoded. However they aren't even encoded with htmlspecialchars(). It just echoes out the code

```
&#9415;
```

Does PHP have any built-in functions to solve this? Thanks

**Edit** just to say what I am trying to do:

I have text fields to input and add to a database which displays in a table below.
When I enter any other character like < > &, it enters straight into the database as one character.

I am trying to make Ⓡ and Ⓒ always go in as one character as well (instead of 6).

I am only encoding on output in the table so certain characters don't break the website.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that the entity doesn't decode when using `html_entity_decode` is likely that the *target character set* given to `html_entity_decode` is still the default ISO-8859-1. ISO-8859-1 cannot encode "Ⓡ" (the CIRCLED LETTER R), but it *can* encode "®" (the REGISTERED MARK).

So, first, to decode it correctly:

```
html_entity_decode('&#9415;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')
```

But secondly, "Ⓡ" and "®" are not the same character, and you probably don't want "Ⓡ".

Comment: This converts it to `â“‡` it seems

Comment: @foxy You need to start by learning something about encodings: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/), then [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: Thanks. From reading those and some testing I think our database is actually the problem. It's Latin1_General_CI_AS. The site encoding was ISO-8859-1, when I changed it to UTF-8 the Ⓡ showed as a single character in the source and everything. Just the database wasn't having it as it doesn't have that character in that encoding?
Thanks again